# range-based access of modified elements

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

This is a simplified instance of actual code. The goal was to provide access to container elements via range-based loops BUT have the elements changed on-the-fly (here ints are squared) without exposing the change.

The code works but seems overly complicated and unreadable. What simplification did I miss?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using ivec_t = std::vector<int>;
class A {
    ivec_t vec;
public:
    A(const ivec_t& v) : vec(v) {}
    class sq_class {
        class iter {
            ivec_t::iterator ivit;
        public:
            iter(ivec_t::iterator the_ivit) : ivit(the_ivit) {}
            bool operator!=(const iter& other) { return ivit != other.ivit; }
            iter& operator++()                 { ++ivit; return *this; }
            int operator*()                    { return (*ivit)*(*ivit); } // <-------------------
        };
        ivec_t ivec;
    public:
        sq_class(ivec_t& the_ivec) : ivec(the_ivec) {}
        iter begin()   { return iter(ivec.begin()); }
        iter end()     { return iter(ivec.end()); }
    };
    sq_class squares() { return sq_class(vec); }
};

main()
{
    A a({1,2,4});

    // expected output: 1, 4, 16,
    for (auto item : a.squares())
        std::cerr << item << ", ";

    std::cerr << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Use more `const`? If you do this regularly and want it shorter, you need to put that stuff into a helper (boost provides one already).

Comment: I tried const in several places but got lots of compile errors with g++.

Comment: _"The code works "_ Really? `main.cpp:27:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations`

Comment: Yes, I copied it back into a file and it compiles with `g++ --std=c++11 t.cpp`. This is g++ version 5.3.1

Comment: I do not see a reason for all this code here. squares() returns new object that contains copy of original vector and uses a lot of code to return square of each element instead of element in operator*... IF you create a copy of original vector - Just use transform in the squares function and generate the vector that contains squares of original data. Return this vector - that's all. All the rest could be removed in this approach.

Comment: This would square all elements even if I break the loop as soon as `item > 10` for example. But you're right, that would be an idea under specific circumstances.

Comment: Is this simple enough? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a66a34490a700b49 -- Requires [Eric Niebler's range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

Comment: That's nice, thanks. Any STL-only solutions?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I will accept if you make an answer out of your code. This looks like it will be in C++20.